# Spark dataframe from dynamic schema Or filter out rows that do not satisfy the schema

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I have written a kafka producer that tails the contents of a log file(format:csv).The kafka consumer is a streaming application that creates a JavaDStream.
using forEachRDD method,I'm splitting each line of file over the delimiter ',' and creating Row object.I have specified schema that has 7 columns.
Then I am creating dataframe using the JavaRDD and schema.
But the problem here is that,all the rows in the log file do not have same number of columns.
Thus, is there any way to filter out such rows that do not satisfy the schema or to create schema dynamically based on the row content?
Following is the part of the code:

```
JavaDStream<String> msgDataStream =directKafkaStream.map(new Function<Tuple2<String, String>, String>() {
            @Override
            public String call(Tuple2<String, String> tuple2) {
                return tuple2._2();
            }
        });
msgDataStream.foreachRDD(new VoidFunction<JavaRDD<String>>() {
            @Override
            public void call(JavaRDD<String> rdd) {
                JavaRDD<Row> rowRDD = rdd.map(new Function<String, Row>() {
                    @Override
                    public Row call(String msg) {
                        String[] splitMsg=msg.split(",");
                        Object[] vals = new Object[splitMsg.length];
                        for(int i=0;i<splitMsg.length;i++)
                        {
                            vals[i]=splitMsg[i].replace("\"","").trim();
                        }

                        Row row = RowFactory.create(vals);
                        return row;
                    }
                });

                //Create Schema
                StructType schema = DataTypes.createStructType(new StructField[] {
                        DataTypes.createStructField("timeIpReq", DataTypes.StringType, true),DataTypes.createStructField("SrcMac", DataTypes.StringType, true),
                        DataTypes.createStructField("Proto", DataTypes.StringType, true),DataTypes.createStructField("ACK", DataTypes.StringType, true),
                        DataTypes.createStructField("srcDst", DataTypes.StringType, true),DataTypes.createStructField("NATSrcDst", DataTypes.StringType, true),
                        DataTypes.createStructField("len", DataTypes.StringType, true)});

                //Get Spark 2.0 session


                Dataset<Row> msgDataFrame = session.createDataFrame(rowRDD, schema);
```

Comment: Do you need to use Java? I could offer you a solution in Scala. Would it be of help?

Comment: Yes..I am using Java since I'm more comfortable with it.But if you can provide a solution in Scala too,that would be of great help! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way to remove rows that do not match the expected schema is to use `flatMap` with a `Option` type, also, if your target is to build a DataFrame, we use the same `flatMap` step to apply a schema to the data. This is facilitated in Scala by the use of `case class`es.

```
// Create Schema
case class NetInfo(timeIpReq: String, srcMac: String, proto: String, ack: String, srcDst: String, natSrcDst: String, len: String)

val netInfoStream = msgDataStream.flatMap{msg => 
  val parts = msg.split(",")
  if (parts.size == 7) {  //filter out messages with unmatching set of fields
    val Array(time, src, proto, ack, srcDst, natSrcDst, len) = parts // use a extractor to get the different parts in variables
    Some(NetInfo(time, src, proto, ack, srcDst, natSrcDst, len)) // return a valid record
  } else {
    None  // We don't have a valid. Return None
  }
}

netInfoStream.foreachRDD{rdd =>
    import sparkSession.implicits._ 
    val df = rdd.toDF() // DataFrame transformation is possible on RDDs with a schema (based on a case class)
    // do stuff with the dataframe
}
```

Regarding:

> all the rows in the log file do not have same number of columns.

Assuming that they all represent the same kind of data but with potentially some columns missing, the right strategy would be to either filter out the incomplete data (like exemplified here) or use optional values in a defined schema if there is a deterministic way to know what fields are missing. This requirement should be posed to the upstream applications that generate the data. It's common to represent missing values in CSV with empty comma sequences (e.g. `field0,,field2,,,field5`)

A dynamic schema to handle per-row differences would not make sense, as there would be no way to apply that to complete `DataFrame` composed of rows with different schemas.